# Is there a good textbook for understanding literary techniques?

Tags: technique, resources

I want to really understand literary techniques. I want to be able to say "Ah, I see this writer is making use of assonance," or "I think I will use a simile here instead of a metaphor." There are glossaries for this on the internet, but I am looking for something in a textbook format, that takes me through these concepts in the form of lessons and exercises.

Could anyone please recommend such a book?

Comment: Interesting question, look forward to suggestions from others because the only books I know of are glossaries/dictionaries e.g. The Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms.

Answer (score 4):

Not an exercise book, but a reference: [A Glossary of Literary Terms,](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495898023) M.H. Abrams. The current edition is about twice the size of the one I picked up in college... maybe I need to upgrade! :)